# Angular JS NaN Handling

Tags: angularjs

I am having an issue with NaNs when they are on a scope property. They come from the server as NaNs, so assume that there is nothing that I can do to change that.

I have a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/9e7Hy/83/

The first directive is passed 1, and it works as expected.

The second directive is passed NaN.

I have a watch on the directive, and if the value is NaN, then the scope.nan property is set to true, and scope.value should be set to 10. The scope.value property never changes, but the scope.nan property does. It seems to be an issue with the watchers within the angular code itself and it must be because NaN!==NaN. If you change NaN in the example to "undefined", everything works as expected.

The watcher..

```
scope.$watch('value',function(nv,ov){

                if(angular.isDefined(nv)&&isNaN(nv)){

                   scope.value=10;
                   scope.nan=true;
                }
            },true);
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in this way:

```
.directive('rnStepper', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            nan:'='
        },
        template: '<button ng-click="decrement()">-</button>' +
                  '<div>{{value}}</div>' +
                  '<button ng-click="increment()">+</button>',
        link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, ngModel) {

            ngModel.$render = function(){
                if(isNaN(ngModel.$modelValue)){
                    scope.value = 10;                    
                    scope.nan=true;
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(scope.value);
                }
                else
                    scope.value=ngModel.$modelValue;
            }
            scope.increment = function() {
                scope.value++;
                ngModel.$setViewValue(scope.value);
            }
            scope.decrement = function() {
                scope.value--;
                ngModel.$setViewValue(scope.value);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aartek/9e7Hy/89/

With `ngModel.$modelValue` you can read the model value. With `ngModel.$setViewValue` you updates model value and you should do if every time you want to give controller updated data. Check the description of both functions here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

If you've never worked before with ngModel, check this short video: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-using-ngmodel-in-custom-directives

Comment: My confusion is why does it work when the initial value is a valid number?

With this method, I have to keep track of updating model values within my directive, but if that is how I have to do it, then so be it.

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea why your code doesn't work. It's a really strange behavior for me.